# Work distribution algorithm in C (do while issue)

Tags: c, algorithm, do-while

So I'm playing with developing an algorithm to evenly distribute work among threads, but it's somewhat unique. The work being done is file comparisons where we have a list of files (let's say 10 files). We don't want to compare file 1 to file 1, so each file would skip comparing itself. File 1 would compare itself to files 2 through 10, file 2 would compare itself to files 3 through 10, etc. So as we move down the list of file compares, the number of file compares drops. Here is the little snippet I'm having issues with (specifically the do-while loop)

```
// Get first pass file chunks
printf("Split approximation: ");
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
{
    file_chunks[i] = (int)floor((double)num_file_compares / (double)num_threads);
    printf("%d ", file_chunks[i]);
}
printf("\n");

// Adjust file chunks to contain all files
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
{
    file_chunk_sum = file_chunk_sum + file_chunks[i];
}
append_count = num_file_compares - file_chunk_sum;
printf("Need to append last %d\n", append_count);

append_index = num_threads;
do
{
    printf("im in the do while...\n");
    printf("append count is: %d\n", append_count);
    printf("why am i here?\n");
    append_index = append_index - 1;
    file_chunks[append_index] = file_chunks[append_index] + 1;
    append_count = append_count - 1;
} while (append_count > 0);

printf("Final split: ");
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", file_chunks[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

With the input of 20 files (190 file compares) and 5 threads, the split approximation would be an even split of 38 file compares per thread. The append count is 0, but it still jumps into the do-while loop. Any idea why?

The output of those `printf`'s is

```
Number of files: 20
Number of threads: 5
Number of file compares: 190
Split approximation: 38 38 38 38 38
Need to append last 0
im in the do while...
append count is: 0
why am i here?
Final split: 38 38 38 38 39
```

Comment: Are the files stored on disk? Then reading the files will likely be much slower than comparing them.

Comment: I'm not really worried about the file comparison part, just the workload distribution. Specifically why the do-while loop is being executed when `append_count` = 0

Comment: why not? the condition is at the end of the `do while` loop, not at the begin.

Comment: So then would I have to wrap the do-while in an if to check the value of `append_count`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 'do while' is always executed at least once. If you don't want it to behave that way, try using a regular 'while'.

Answer (score 3):

Rather that using `do`...`while`, you just want to use `while`.  This performs the check at the top of the loop instead of the bottom.

```
while (append_count > 0)
{
    printf("im in the while...\n");
    printf("append count is: %d\n", append_count);
    printf("why am i here?\n");
    append_index = append_index - 1;
    file_chunks[append_index] = file_chunks[append_index] + 1;
    append_count = append_count - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"do while" loops in C always execute at least once , what you want is "while" loops

Comment: Ugh. That's what I get for thinking C was as good as Fortran ;)

Comment: I learned C as my first language ,so to me, languages that use the same convention as Fortran feel weird :)

Answer (score 0):

I gather from a comment that you're used to Fortran.  Here's how to write your code in more C-like C:

```
// Get first pass file chunks
printf("Split approximation: ");   // fputs("...", stdout);  is a good choice for non-formatted output, but it's clunkier to write.
// puts() confusingly tacks on a newline while fputs() doesn't, so puts(s) *isn't* just fputs(s, stdout).
// Every time you use printf, remember that the first argument is being parsed as a format string, so you have to make sure you don't use a % in it, unless you write printf("%s", "...")


for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
{
// opening brace on a line by itself is a waste of space, IMO, except for the first line of a function.
// but it's better to be consistent than to use your personal favourite style.

    file_chunks[i] = num_file_compares / num_threads;   // what's wrong with integer division here?  I think this rounds the same as your old // (int)floor((double)num_file_compares / (double)num_threads);
    printf("%d ", file_chunks[i]);
}
putchar('\n');   // here we can use a lighter-weight i/o function

int file_chunk_sum = 0;  // don't forget to initialize your variables.  And in C99 (or C++), many people prefer to declare them near where they're used instead of in a big block at the top of a function.
// Adjust file chunks to contain all files
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)  // don't use a loop to do this: see below
{
    file_chunk_sum += file_chunks[i];   // += saves human readers of your code from having to notice that it's the same variable on both sides of the =
}
append_count = num_file_compares - file_chunk_sum;
/* or you could have started with int append_count = num_f_c; and subtracted f_c[i] in the loop
 * or instead of summing, you could just take advantage of the fact that every f_c[i] has the same known value.
 * integer multiply FTW.
 * or even just make use of the remainder from your integer division and save the multiply.  (x86 at least computes remainders at the same time as dividend, so % is free if you're already doing /.)
 */
// append_count = num_file_compares - (file_chunks[0] * num_threads);

// append_count = num_file_compares % num_threads;  // or remainder

printf("Need to append last %d\n", append_count);

// append_index = num_threads;  // make this a loop variable if you like.  Some people would consider packing too much stuff into a for loop to be less readable
// actually, we can simplify the loop a *lot* by getting rid of unneeded variables.  Adjust if desired to still put the remainder counts on the later indices, rather than earlier.

for (int i=append_count ; i > 0 ; i--)
{
    // count downwards to print a descending count, same as your old code
    printf("I'm in the append loop...\n"  // nobody like "im" instead of I'm.
           "append count is: %d\n"
           "why am i here?\n", append_count);
        /* string literals concatenate automatically.
         * Writing multi-line string constants this way is generally preferred
         * to having literal newlines inside double-quotes.  That can lead to problems with line endings (Unix lf vs. DOS cr/lf vs. Mac cr).
         */
    file_chunks[i]++;   // Much easier to read ++ when using long variable names.
}

printf("Final split: ");
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", file_chunks[i]);
}
putchar('\n');
```